If $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{2^{k}\left({k^2+2k+2}\right)}{(k+1)(k+2)}=2^{15}-2^{11}-1$. Then value of $n$ is

If $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{2^{k}\left({k^2+2k+2}\right)}{(k+1)(k+2)}=2^{15}-2^{11}-1$. Then value of $n$ is

Attempt: I tried to form telescopic sequence.
First I wrote $k^{2}+2k+2=(k+1)^2+1$ but this is not helping me.
Then I tried to write $k^2+2k+2=(k+1)(k+2)-(k)$ but this is not helping me either.
So anyone here give me some hints?

$(k^2+2k+2)/((k+1)(k+2))$ is less than, but very close to $1$, so this should be less than, but close to, $\sum_{k=1}^n 2^k = 2^{n+1}-2$.  The most plausible candidate is $n=14$. Does that work?

@RobertIsrael I understood your method to approximate but is there any way so that I get directly this form

It turns out that $$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2^k (k^2+2k+2)}{(k+1)(k+2)} = \frac{n+1}{n+2} 2^{n+1}-1$$ Prove by induction, or use partial fractions.

Try again to form a telescopic sequence. Obviously, ${k^2+2k+2\over(k+1)(k+2)}=1-{k\over(k+1)(k+2)} = 1-k\cdot\left(\frac1{k+1}-\frac1{k+2}\right)=1-{k\over  k+1} + {k\over k+2}=1-\left(1-\frac1{k+1}\right)+\left(1-\frac2{k+2}\right)=\dots$

@IvanNeretin but I think It will form a harmonic sequence

@mathophile Write it out fully (Edit your post to show your work). Can you explain why we definitely will get a harmonic sequence? Hints: Recall the $2^k$. Also $16 = 2^4$.

@IvanNeretin Thanks. Got it

As you said, you can divide the sum as
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2^k(k^2+2k+2)}{(k+1)(k-2)}=\sum_{k=1}^n2^k-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k\,2^k}{(k+1)(k+2)}$$
The first sum is just $2^{n+1}-1$. For the second sum, you have
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k\,2^k}{(k+1)(k+2)}=\sum_{k=1}^n2^k\left(\frac{k}{k+1}-\frac{k}{k+2}\right)$$
Now,
$$\frac{k}{k+1}=1-\frac{1}{k+1}$$
$$\frac{k}{k+2}=1-\frac{2}{k+2}$$
Can you take it from here?

As an aside, typically for partial fractions the degree of the numerator is smaller tan the denominator. So it would be written as $ 2^k ( \frac{ 2}{k+2} - \frac{ 1}{ k+1} )$ directly.

@CalvinLin: I wasn't doing partial fractions, I just used the simple $$\frac1a-\frac1{a+1}=\frac1{a(a+1)}$$ without any thought and did some simplification.

You stated "partial fractions gives", hence my comment.

RHS is equal to $2^{15}-2^{11}-1=30719=A$. Consider the function $f(x)=\dfrac{2^x(x^2+2x+2}{x^2+3x+2}$
$\lfloor f(15)\rfloor=30960\gt A$ so $n\lt15$
$\lfloor f(11)\rfloor=1903$ and $1903\times 11=20933\lt A$ so $n\gt11$
We have $11\lt n\lt15$
Now $\lfloor f(13)+f(12)+f(11)+10\times f(10)\rfloor=22878\lt A$
Consequently it remains to check only $\boxed{n=14}$. The only way I have to verify if $n=14$ is correct is to make the sum $f(1)+f(2)+\cdots+f(14)$ which is straightforward to do. I don't have another. If $n=14$ does not work then the statement would be false.

Who are you downvoter? Are you unhappy?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-diB65scQU
